# Extracting significance score from AER coeftest results in R

Tags: r

Calling

```
coeftest(m)
```

returns 
    z test of coefficients:

```
         Estimate Std. Error  z value  Pr(>|z|)    
lenDelta  0.26592    0.13038   2.0397   0.04138 *  
-2|-1    -2.59586    0.24090 -10.7758 < 2.2e-16 ***
-1|0     -0.81155    0.13558  -5.9860 2.150e-09 ***
0|1       0.73271    0.13394   5.4706 4.486e-08 ***
1|2       1.98097    0.19182  10.3271 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I know I can access the individual numerical values with

```
coeftest(m)[1,4]
```

From this I can get the significance code in a straightforward way.

However, how do I access the significance code string "*" associated with lenDelta?

The structure of the object is as follows

```
str(coeftest(m))
```

returns the following output

```
 coeftest [1:5, 1:4] 0.266 -2.596 -0.812 0.733 1.981 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "lenDelta" "-2|-1" "-1|0" "0|1" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "z value" "Pr(>|z|)"
 - attr(*, "method")= chr "z test of coefficients"
```

Complete reproducible example (sourced from [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/No-P-values-in-polr-summary-td4678547.html))

```
## data 
library("foreign")
dat <- read.dta("ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/ologit.dta")
## model 
library("MASS")
m <- polr(apply ~ pared + public + gpa, data = dat, Hess = TRUE)
## coefficient test
library("AER")
coeftest(m)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example including the `library` call?  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/633251).

Comment: how about `stringr::str_extract(capture.output(coeftest(fm)),"\\*+")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `print` method for `coeftest` objects internally calls `printCoefmat` (just like the `summary` method for `lm` or `glm` objects). And this leverages the function `symnum`, by default using the cutpoints shown in the legend of coefficient tests/summaries.

To call this by hand you can do the following. (I'm using a simpler model here because I had problems accessing the data at the UCLA site.)

Fit a model:

```
m <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
```

Extract the p-values from coeftest:

```
pv <- coeftest(m)[,4]
```

Cut the p-values into significance groups:

```
symnum(pv, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE,
  cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1),
  symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " ")
)
## (Intercept)       speed 
##           *         *** 
## attr(,"legend")
## [1] 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Comment: Actually, my question was more in the direction of how would I parse or get the significance code from the object returned by coeftest, rather then to compute them from the p-values myself. Essentially, the object somewhere contains the "Signif. codes:" line, I am just unable to access it.  Put in another way, I do not understand the structure of the object as returned by the str() call.  What does .$ : chr mean? How is it accessed?

Comment: The line starting with `Signif. codes` is _not_ part of the `coeftest` object - the latter is simply a numeric matrix with suitable labels. The `Signif. codes` legend is produced on-the-fly by the `print` method (as I tried to convey in my answer above) using the function `symnum()`. This also sets up the legend.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Is there no way to convert the object to a matrix or data frame that can be easier accessed?

Comment: You need to be more specific: What exactly do you want to access easily? The `coeftest()` _is_ a matrix where the 4th column pertains to the p-values. It's just that the significance stars are not part of that matrix. To obtain groups of significances you can simply `cut()` the p-values or use `symnum()` as shown in my answer. If you want something different, please provide more details...possibly in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the below function `ctdf` to convert the `coeftest` print output to a data frame that can be easily accessed with conventional methods such as `r2$sig` . To specifically access the significance stars of "lenDelta" use `r2[row.names(r2)=="lenDelta","sig"]`

```
# Obtain coeftest object
r1=coeftest(m)                         

#*** Function to convert coeftest results object to data frame
ctdf=function(x){
  rt=list()                             # generate empty results list
  for(c in 1:dim(x)[2]) rt[[c]]=x[,c]   # writes column values of x to list
  rt=as.data.frame(rt)                  # converts list to data frame object
  names(rt)=names(x[1,])                # assign correct column names
  rt[,"sig"]=symnum(rt$`Pr(>|z|)`, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE,cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1),symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))
  return(rt)
}

# Apply function
r2=ctdf(r1) # returns a data frame that can be accessed normally
```